# A lemma from Jarden's and Lubotzky's paper 'Elementary equivalence of profinite groups'

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, model-theory, formal-languages

I have a question about a reduction argument from
Jarden's and Lubotzky's paper  ['Elementary equivalence of
profinite groups'](http://132.64.72.10/%7Ealexlub/PAPERS/Elementary%20equivalence%20of%20profinite%20groups/Elementary%20equivalence%20of%20profinite%20groups.pdf) in Lemma 1.1 on page 3:

*Lemma 1.1: For each positive integer $n$ and each finite group $A$ of
order at most $n$ there exists a sentence $ \theta $ of
$\mathcal{L} \text{(group)} $
such that for every group $G$ of order at most $n$
the sentence $ \theta $ holds in $G$ if and only if $A$ is a quotient of $G$.* $\tag{L}$

The proof begins with a reduction step I
not understand:

*Proof*:
It suffices to prove that for every positive integer $n$ and
for every group $A$ of
order $d$ dividing $n$ there exists a sentence $ \theta $ of
$\mathcal{L} \text{(group)} $ with the following property:
for every group $G$ of order $n$ the sentence $ \theta $ holds in $G$
if and only if $G$ has a normal
subgroup $M$ such that $G/M \cong A$. [..]        $\tag{L'}$

Assume we have proved (L'). Why the claim (L) of the lemma follows
immediately from (L'); in other words why is sufficient to show
only claim (L'), which is seemingly weaker as the claim (L)?

I have already asked identical question in [MathStackEx](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3911907/lemma-from-paper-on-elementary-equivalence-of-profinite-groups-by-jarden-lubot)
but a comment by Noah Schweber stresses another important viewpoint:
That this lemma 1.1 is an elementary consequence of a much stronger
statement about structures in context of finite languages.
That's true, but that was not my original concern: my original concern
is just about the logic of the proof itself: why (L') *implies* (L).

Comment: I'm actually puzzled: why isn't it trivially true (enumerate those finite groups $F_1,\dots,F_m$ of order $\le n$ admitting $A$ as quotient, and let $\theta(G)$ say: $G$ is isomorphic to one of the $F_i$)?

Comment: but how do you construct this 
first order sentence (ie a formula
without free variables) of $\mathcal{L} \text{(group)}$
explicitely? You wrote how this sentence acts on
groups but not how this sentence internally looks like.

Recall that the second part of the proof of the lemma is devoted
to construct explicitely the sentence which satisfy (L').
Of course, if you can construct the sentence which satisfies
(L) by hand, then we are indeed also done.

Comment: And yes, there are probably a lot of multiple other ways to prove this Lemma 1.1 as done in the paper, eg maybe by making a clever guess for a $\theta$ which directly satisfies $(L)$ as you suggested, or recognizing this lemma as speical case of a stronger result like Noah did. But I'm just interested in the nacked reason which $(L')$ imply $(L)$.

Comment: If $H=\{h_1,\dots,h_k\}$ is a given finite group and $h_ih_j=h_{s(i,j)}$, a sentence $\theta(G)$ saying "$G$ is isomorphic to $H$" can be given as $\exists g_1,\dots,g_k: $ $(\forall g:(g=g_1)\vee (g=g_2)\dots\vee (g=g_k))$ $\wedge$ $(g_1\neq g_2)$ $\wedge$ $(g_1\neq g_3)$ $\dots$ $\wedge (g_{k-1}\neq g_k)$ $\wedge$ $(g_1g_2=g_{s(1,2)})$ $\wedge$ $(g_1g_3=g_{s(1,3)})$ $\dots$ $\wedge$ $(g_{k-1}g_k=g_{s(k-1,k)})$.

Comment: Apart from what YCor wrote, how is $(L')$ not just a trivial reformulation of $(L)$? If $A$ is a quotient of $G$, then the order of $A$ divides the order of $G$, and by definition, $A$ is a quotient of $G$ iff there is a normal subgroup $M$ of $G$ such that $G/M\simeq A$. So why do you think it is weaker?

Comment: Or is the concern just that $(L')$ requires $|G|=n$, while $(L)$ only requires $|G|\le n$? This is trivial to fix by just taking the disjunction of the sentences corresponding to each order up to $n$.

Comment: The point is this is not an ad-hoc proof, it's just a basic observation, which holds in arbitrary structures (with finitely many laws/relations). So I was wondering if I'm missing something, or if they have a particular reason to exhibit some particular formula.

Comment: @YCor I had a look at the paper, and the situation is actually quite bizarre: not only they do not need any particular property of their particular formula, they actually do not need the complicated statement of Lemma 1.1 at all! They only use it once in the proof of the main result, to show that two particular nonisomorphic finite groups can be distinguished by a sentence, but this can be shown more directly and much more easily using the observation in your comment above.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Yes, exactly my concern is focused only on the requirements $\vert G \vert  \ge n $
for $(L)$ and $\vert G \vert =n $ for $(L')$.
Let call $\theta_{L}(n, A)$ the sentence we are looking 
for in $(L)$ and
and $\theta_{L'}(n', A)$ for $(L')$.

I think I have meanwhile I solution but I think there is
a subtle problem why if we take for $\theta(n, A)$ the
disjunction 
$\bigvee_{n' \le n} \theta_{L'}(n', A)$ as you suggested, would lead to a wrong choice. 
Instead I claim that the correct choice for $\theta(n, A)$
should be the modified disjunction

Comment: $\bigvee_{n' \le n} (\theta_{L'}(n', A) \wedge \psi(n'))$
where for every finite group $G$ the 
sentence $ \psi(n')(G)$ is defined to be true (="1") iff 
$\vert G \vert = n'$.

Comment: All right, so add a “$\psi(n')$” formula. But either way, this is just a trivial manipulation. This is a site for research-level questions, this question belongs to math.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Why do I think that this modification of your suggestion to take
for $\theta_{L}(n, A)$ just the disjunction 
$\bigvee_{n' < n} \theta_{L'}(n', A)$ is neccessary? Assume we choose
$\theta_{L}(n, A):= \bigvee_{n' < n} \theta_{L'}(n', A)$
Let $G$ be a group with $\vert G \vert := s \le n$ and 
$\theta(n, A)_{L}(G)$ is true. Then there exist a $t \le n$ with
$\theta_{L'}(t, A)(G)$ is true. 
If $\theta_{L'}(s, A)(G)$ is true, then
we are done, because by definition of $\theta_{L'}(s, A)(G)$
this implies $A$ is quotient of $G$, ie $A=G/M$.

Comment: Now assume that $\theta_{L'}(s, A)(G)$ is false but 
$\theta_{L'}(t, A)(G)$ is true for a $t \neq s$.
That's a serious problem since if $\theta_{L'}(s, A)(G)$
is false, then there exist no normal $M \subset G$ with 
$A \cong G/M$, right.
The point is that recall what is the definition of
$\theta_{L'}(t, A)$? The sentence is that for every group 
$G$ with $\vert G \vert =t$ (!) we have equivalence:
$\theta_{L'}(t, A)(G) $ is true iff $A \cong G/M$.
But for any $G$ with $\vert G \vert =s \neq t$ there
is no condition when $\theta_{L'}(t, A)(G) $ is true
or false, right?

Comment: But for any $G$ with $\vert G \vert =s \neq t$ there
is no condition when $\theta_{L'}(t, A)(G) $ should be true
or false, right?